# VS Code extension recommendations for projects

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to enforce TS Linting on projects opened with Visual Studio Code.  [The docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_workspace-recommended-extensions) say you can provide a list of extension recommendations for workspaces, but what if we don't use workspaces and we just open project folders? Is there a way to prompt users who open a project to install TS Lint?

I've tried creating .vscode\extensions.json with the following:

```
{
    "recommendations": [
        "eg2.tslint",
    ]
}
```

Any feedback would be helpful.

Answer (score 30):

Once you create a `.vscode\extensions.json`, vscode users should see this notification when they open the workspace/folder:

[image]

This should work both if the project is opened as a folder or as a workspace

Comment: Good to know that it should be working for folders as well.  I wasn't seeing this notification when I tested it out for myself.  Would the user only see the notification on the first time opening the project? I will continue to tinker and can mark this answer when I get it to work.

Comment: Make sure to try this in a new workspace. We will not show this notification again if you dismissed it previously

Comment: @MattBierner Is there a way to reset things to test this locally to make sure we have things configured correctly before publishing it for new users? I tried uninstalling the extensions, but I must have already dismissed the initial notification.

Comment: @mattBierner: I would also like to have it show again. First time use of vscode. Repo had a recommendations list. I can't figure out how to get it to show and install *it's* recommendations again. Dunno if I dismissed it at first launch or not. Only shows a huge generic list recommendations, not the repo's list of recommendations. I try searching for the items listed in the repo, but the prefix (before 1st dot) comes up nothing. The portion after the last dot *does* come up, but there are many options with that name, I have no idea if I am clicking on the correct one. Same Q for Rec settings

Comment: Is there a way to reset, ie show the dialog again to install or view the repo's recommended extensions? It seems there should be some method to do this at some point post the very first time you open up vs code and the repo! Anyone can change their mind. And new users have no idea what is going on. Defaulting to "no" when you have no idea why or who is wanting to install stuff the first time you open vs code and/or a new repo. Usually you have a task you want to accomplish immediately anyway, and that dialog, even if you do know what it is for, can just be in the way *in that moment*.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for visual studio 2022?